# Atualizando ID da sessão para obter maior segurança

Tags: php, session

para eu manter os dados da minha sessão mais seguros, eu posso atualizar o id  da sessão em cada página, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); session_regenerate_id();

}
```

Isso vai sobrecarregar o servidor?

Comment: Esse código aí não faz nenhum sentido. Se vai usar sessão, o session_start() não tem que estar dentro de if. Da mesma forma, o session_regenerate_id() não ia funcionar sem a session, continua não fazendo sentido depender do if. Quanto a ficar mudando o id de sessão, o maior "benefício" que você vai ter no atual estágio é criar dor de cabeça pra debugar seu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sobrecarregará não, só se você tiver tipo milhares, ou milhões ou um pouco mais que isso de páginas kk, fora isso não influenciará tanto no servidor

Comment: ou então, posso atualizar o meu id somente em determinadas paginas? O que é mais coerente?

Comment: Eu não me preocuparia em ficar mudando tanto o id, pode fazer isso em algumas paginas, ou somente quando há alguma alteraçao nao sessão, mas se preocupe mais em criptografar os dados que estaram nessa sessao. Mas qualquer segurança a mais é bem vinda

Comment: entendi. obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.